# Wrong output is generating while using linklist

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I created a program to make a link list in c++
I have a class `CL` I am trying to insert nodes at head again and again but this is giving unexpected results.

**I tried to insert Nodes using this method**

```
class Node {
    public:
        string name;
        Node* Next;
};
class CL {
public:
    Node* head;

public:
    CL(void) { head = NULL; } // constructor
    Node* insertAtHead(string name); //insert at start of list
    void displayList(void);
};
int main()
{
CL poliop;
poliop.insertAtHead("am");
poliop.insertAtHead("a");
poliop.displayList();
}
```

```
void CL::displayList(void){
Node* t;
t = head;
while(t != NULL){
    cout<<(t->name)<<endl;
    t = t->Next;
}
}
```

```
Node* CL::insertAtHead(string name)
{
Node temp;
temp.name = name;
temp.Next = head;
head = &temp;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
.
.
.
```

Comment: pointers to local variables. a print function that modifies the list.  code that cannot possibly compile. mismatched names. other stuff

Comment: @NeilButterworth did,nt understand what you want to convey

Comment: i want to convey that everything you have written is wrong

Comment: @NeilButterworth please explain

Comment: He did; in the first comment. 1. What do you think `head` points to *after* `insertAtHead` returns? Not `temp`; it's gone and destroyed. 2. `displayList ` modifies head as it walks the list, so even if the list were properly built that function would leak the entire thing into ether.

Comment: i suggest deleting this question, and posting a new one featuring actual code

Comment: @NeilButterworth it is actual code i tried

Comment: it isn't - it won't compile

Comment: @NeilButterworth now it is actual code it is compiling

Comment: no it still will not compile

Comment: @NeilButterworth why ?it is compiling

Comment: well, what is "t"? how are you calling those member functions?

Comment: @poliop -- When you post code, it should be *complete*, not bits and pieces where we have to put it together like a jigsaw puzzle.  We should be able to copy the text from the code in the question, make *no* changes to it, compile it, run it.  The reason why this is important is because if we go ahead and fill in all the missing pieces, the code we end up with will be different than your code, thus possibly never duplicating the issue.  [Here is the current state of trying to compile the code you posted](https://godbolt.org/z/GM3f33ndM).

Comment: Example, on line `t = head;` `t` is an undeclared variable, and will not compile, so we know the code you have given did not produce the output (or you have a really weird "C++" compiler that's not really compiling C++). But anyway, the heart of the matter is the difference between temporary variables allocated on the stack (local variables, like `Node temp;`) which do not remain after the function is finished, and variables on the heap (generally with `new` or C-like `malloc()`) which remain for the life of the program. You're using the first, but want the second.

Comment: @JohnBayko t is ```Node* t``` check previous line from it

Comment: @JohnBayko if ```Node temp``` finish after function call is completed what should i do in c++

Comment: @JohnBayko yes it was not there my mistake but added to question because it was part of my actual code

Comment: As I said, use `new` (as in `Node* temp = new Node;`) and `delete` if it's no longer needed before the program exits.

Answer (score 0):

Just a few quick things that could be causing this:

1. In your `main()` function, you don't declare a `CL` object. So when you make calls to

   ```cpp
   insertAtHead("am")
   insertAtHead("a")
   displayList()
   ```

   it doesn't use those `CL` functions and does something else. Maybe do something like:

   ```cpp
   CL list = CL();
   list.insertAtHead("am");
   list.insertAtHead("a");
   list.displayList();
   ```
2. Since you are using pointers for Nodes, instead of `NULL` you should probably use `nullptr`:

   ```cpp
   public:
      CL(void) { head = nullptr; } // constructor
   ```
3. In your `displayList(void)` function, you're using an unidentified variable `x`?

   ```cpp
   cout<<(head->x)<<endl;
   ```

   Maybe it's supposed to be this instead:

   ```cpp
   cout<<(head->name)<<endl;
   ```

   **BUT**, more importantly, in your `displayList(void)` function you traverse the linked list using the `head` pointer, in effect, you end up assigning the end of the list to be equal to the `head` of the linked list as soon as the `displayList(void)` function finishes execution. I would recommend changing it to look like this instead:

   ```cpp
   void LinkList::displayList(void){
      Node* temp = head;
      while(temp != nullptr){
         cout<<(temp->name)<<endl;
         temp = temp->Next;
      }
   }
   ```

I hope one of these things helps you fix the issue of undefined behavior you're dealing with! c:

Comment: I am doing the same but still ouput is wrong. Check my edit in question